# Jmeter Microsoft Azure Authentication to login

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, jmeter

Can someone help to login to an application having Microsoft OAuth authentication using JMeter? I'm having trouble to identify the unique token that is being used in the login call. Is there a way to identify?

Answer (score 0):

Which exactly OAuth?

As of now the following OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect protocols are implemented/supported:

- [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code)
- [OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)
- [OAuth 2.0 auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code)
- [OAuth 2.0 on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)
- [OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

The instructions will differ depending on your application authentication flow and covering all of them with examples in a single answer.

The universal way would be using i.e. [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java) library from the [JSR223 Test Elements using Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) in order to get the access token.

Comment: its OAuth 2.0 @dmitri T

Comment: they are all OAuth 2.0

Comment: is there any example of using MSAL with groovy in jmeter?